# Where does TCP CPU load show up?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, tcp

If connections on Windows 2008 R2 server are *not* being offloaded. Where does the CPU usage caused by processing TCP appear?

So in taskmanager, does it show up as part of the process using the connections, or something else?

Also, does it show up as User time or privileged time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that CPU usage by hardware devices only shows up in Resource Monitor in Windows 2008 R2. The item name will be "System Interrupts".

There's no singular explanatory source for this, but I would love to read one that specifically addresses this if someone finds it.

Sources I've interpreted to get to this conclusion:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddperf/archive/2010/04/04/measuring-processor-utilization-and-queuing-delays-in-windows-applications.aspx
- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/92fa1694-e54e-437b-a109-c5bf2d73bdb4/
- http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/CS-031086.htm
- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/system-interrupts/b2a4ae8d-9c93-40e8-9b88-8bef42083605

If you're looking for specific info about TCP offloading, performance monitor has some good information hidden in the "Per Processor Network Activity Cycles" and "Per Processor Network Interface Card Activity" sections.

EDIT: I took out some blatantly wrong information that I shot from the hip.

Comment: Have any supporting evidence or experience?

Comment: You know, I thought it was so because of prior experience. Further research shows that it may not show up. I'm doing more research to double check.

Comment: @Kyle Okay, better info edited into the answer now. Sorry for the bunk.